# Ensuring that every class that implements an interface is case-insensitive (but case-preserving)

Tags: java

How do i ensure that every class that implements a created interface should have its name be case-insensitive (but case-preserving).

```
public interface OpenmrsMetadata  {

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName();

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name);

    /**
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getDescription();

    /**
     * @param description the description to set
     */
    public void setDescription(String description);

}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: What you want to achieve, can you laborate more

Comment: Everything that implements the interface should have its name be case-insensitive (but case-preserving).

This means that:

creating a metadata with a name "Like This" should preserve that case
later, trying to create another metadata with a name "LIKE THIS" should fail
doing getXyzByName("like this") should find that the metadata with name "Like This"
any search method that returns a List<XyzMetadata> should do a case-insensitive search

Comment: You could write *contract tests* that you run against every implementation of this interface, making sure that examples like the above work as expected.